# How to write a Python dataframe back to Excel File after using GroupBy?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

```
     def Grouping(gr): 
             print(gr, "\n")

     df1 = df.groupby("CONTACT_MOBILE").apply(func=Grouping)


     writer = ExcelWriter("Peacock.xlsx")
     df1.to_excel(writer,"Sheet1",index=False)
     writer.save()
```

Before using `GroupBy`, the dataframe was being written back to Excel File. After using `GroupBy` my program works fine in Jupyter notebook and the dataframe is displayed and the rows are arranged according to "`CONTACT_MOBILE`". But these few lines of code are not working now, even though no errors are there as such.

I wanted to display output in this format.

[Expected Output to be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wwmm.png)

Comment: In the beginning of the program I have already imported ExcelWriter and ExcelFile from Pandas.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Grouping function simply prints it's arguments on the screen, it's not clear for me what this function returns and what it will be in df1 as a result of this apply. It's a strange code. May be you need to return something from function Grouping.

Comment: I am trying to group the contents of the dataframe by Contact Number. I basically want all the rows of dataframe to appear in file, with the rows with same Contact Number appearing together. When I run the program on notebook, dataframe is displayed but it is not written back to the file. df1 is a new dataframe I am trying to create and Peacock is the name of the file to which I want the dataframe to be written to.

Comment: I was first facing a problem in grouping the data. Then I found a solution on the site Towards Data Science.                                                                                             def foo(gr): 
      print(gr, ‘\n’)
 df.groupby(‘species’).apply(func=foo)                          Seeing this, I tried to implement the same in my program. This works fine, but no longer the dataframe is written to the file. The file is blank.Would it help if I send a screenshot of expected output?

Comment: Can't you just write it to CSV? Excel opens CSV files

Comment: @Gustavo Maia. Will try that. Thanks

Comment: I tried using CSV, still the dataframe was not written back. I guess some value needs to be returned from function Grouping, as CrazyElf had said. I am stuck at finding the solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is organized the function `Grouping` dosn't return anything to the dataframe you are trying to group the elements, you function must return something as a result of the application of the `groupby` method. Here is an example:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = [[0, '1'], [0, '2'], [1, '1'], [1, '2']]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a', 'b'])
>>> print(df)

   a  b
0  0  1
1  0  2
2  1  1
3  1  2
```

```py
>>> def grouping(x):
>>>     print(x, '\n')
>>> print(df.groupby('a').apply(func=grouping))

   a  b
0  0  1
1  0  2

   a  b
2  1  1
3  1  2

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Here the method is printing the values of the grouped rows of the dataframe inside the function `grouping` bu the returned dataframe is empty. What you need to do is something like this:

```py
>>> def grouping(x):
>>>     return list(x)
>>> print(df.groupby('a').apply(func=grouping))

a
0    [a, b]
1    [a, b]
dtype: object
```

Now you can have a valid dataframe in a vaiable and print it to wherever you need:

```py
>>> res_df = df.groupby('a').apply(func=grouping).to_csv()
>>> res_df.to_csv('res.csv')
```

And this would be the end result in the CSV file:

```
0,"['a', 'b']"
1,"['a', 'b']"
```